# Como preencher uma propriedade (tipo object) a partir de um formulário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
@model ModelTransaction

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Conta:</label>
    <select asp-for="Account"  class="form-control">
        @{
            foreach (ModelAccount account in (List<ModelAccount>)ViewBag.AccountList)
            {
                <option value="@account">@account.Name</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Este formulário tem como objetivo preencher a propriedade Account do objeto ModelTransaction. Porém, essa propriedade tem um tipo ModelAccount, ou seja, um outro objeto pela tag asp-for. Porém, da maneira como está construído o código acima, a requisição via post desse formulário não preenche a propriedade Account, mesmo tendo definido esse valor no formulário.

Teria alguma forma de preencher esse objeto por este formulário?

Estrutura do ModelTransaction:

```
namespace MyFinances.Models

{
    public class ModelTransaction
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a data")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o valor")]
        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a descrição")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public TransactionType Type { get; set; }
        public ModelUser User { get; set; }
        public ModelAccount Account { get; set; }
        public ModelAccountingPlan AccountingPlan { get; set; }

        public IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }

        public ModelTransaction()
        {

        }

        public ModelTransaction(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
    }
```

Estrutura do ModelAccount:

```
 namespace MyFinances.Models
{
    public class ModelAccount
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome da conta")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o saldo inicial da conta")]
        public decimal InitialBalance { get; set; }

        public ModelUser User { get; set; }
        public IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }


        public ModelAccount()
        {

        }

        public ModelAccount(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você diz na pergunta que faz um post do formulário, mas no trecho que postou na pergunta não tem o <form>, está completo? Seria interessante também postar a controller. Não sei se sua ModelTransaction é sua entidade BD, mas se vc vai enviar esse campo no post não seria interessante ter uma ViewModel que terá o List<ModelAccount>?